# get the path of a Gallery Folder in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, gallery, image-gallery

I know how to programatically get a gallery image (one by one).

Now that the gallery is organised folderwise

Is there a way to select and get the path of a folder in the gallery view...

[image]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993725/how-to-get-path-of-android-galley-folder-dynamically

Comment: can u provide me any src link for solution like u have in screenshot, i need albumwise photos in my own app.

Answer (score 16):

With this method you can get the path of the `Gallery` of your device:

```
private static String getGalleryPath() {
        return photoDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/";   
    }
```

Comment: This works great (+1), but what to do when user has default image/video location set to SD card? How to detect and handle this?

Answer (score 13):

You can get path [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM) but MediaScanner will find every folder on SDCARD with photos.

```
final String path = android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;
```

Comment: Please! give the details, instead just dropping link here, because link may die someday and your answer will be no more useful.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: This is incorrect. DIRECTORY_DCIM only returns the string "DCIM". Not the path.

Answer (score 3):

```
String getGalleryPath() {
    File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    return folder.getAbsolutePath();
}
```