# how to get folder view in my gallery?

Tags: android, gallery, dynamic-folders

I had create on gallery its display image but i am expecting to display folder images
Example: 1. camara image folder 2. all images 3.sdcard images.....this type if its possible how to create please help me....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458752/get-the-path-of-a-gallery-folder-in-android?s=43e1a6cc-b7fa-4daf-8b7d-30e8a24288cc#new-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your answer

**(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/*Imagesfoldername*/")**