# When I try to push a photo onto the android emulator, I am not able to see the photo in Albums

Tags: android, gallery, android-mediascanner

I am new to Android and now trying to retrieve contact photo (thumb nail) from a content provider and set it onto my app. But for that as i am running on an AVD, i pushed some .png photos onto my 2.2 version. Now i tried to create a contact with the photo, but the Gallery is showing "No Media Found", hence i am stuck here.
Please help me in getting the photo visible in gallery.

Note : I am aware of the following facts :

1. I have restarted my AVD to force the Media Scanner to do its initial mockups.
2. Also i have seen the .png file through the File Explorer View of Eclipse Framework.
3. But strangely, I am not able to pull the file off the phone.
4. I have taken help of the link [get the path of a Gallery Folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458752/get-the-path-of-a-gallery-folder-in-android) for understanding the general view on Media Scanner.

Comment: add full-path information to where you put the images.

Comment: Actually i have used the "Push a file onto the device" button on the File Explorer View of Eclipse Framework. What you are suggesting is to get a photo through code execution. but i just dropped the file through the simple importing feature of eclipse. I am trying to ask how to re-scan the SD Card by the media scanner for discovery of the file i uploaded on a whim.

Comment: but you should still know, where do you "push" the file onto your emulator. Please tell us the location.

Comment: I Pushed the .png file in /data/ folder. As mentioned in the above mentioned link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458752/get-the-path-of-a-gallery-folder-in-android), i though if i push the file anywhere in the SD card, it will be known in the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because the application doesn't know if there are images inside `/data`.

Try to put your images in:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Pictures
```

Comment: @ ariefbayu, Thank you for the advice, its working. but can you tell me why the system doesn't know about the images and how can we configure the media scanner or other intrinsic support system application to look for images in /data folder. I know that by knowing about the media scanner properties, it is slightly naive to ask this question, but if any answer is there, then its well solved.

Comment: AFAIK, you are not supposed to be able to access /data/. You can, in emulator or rooted device. This is because /data/ hold android internal and also application code. For user files, you should put it in /mnt/sdcard. If this answer solved your problem, you may want to mark it as accepted answer.